# How to access/inject ObjectBox database in repository in Flutter - Reso Coder DDD

Tags: flutter, dependency-injection, architecture, objectbox, flutter-objectbox

all the examples, I have seen, initialize ObjectBox in a State(less/full)Widget. I am using a layered architecture (currently refactoring to DDD) and wonder, how to inject my ObjectBox properly.

In my repository, I inject the data sources using the injectable and the getit packages with

```dart
@injectable
@LazySingleton (as: IJournalsRepository)
class JournalsRepository implements IJournalsRepository {
  final JournalsRemoteDataSource journalsRemoteDataSource;
  final JournalsLocalDataSource journalsLocalDataSource;
  JournalsRepository(this.journalsLocalDataSource, this.journalsRemoteDataSource);
```

Those packages then create an instance of `JournalsRemoteDataSource` and of `JournalsRemoteDataSource` and inject it into the repository.

The ObjectBox example shows for initialization

```dart
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Store? _store;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    openStore().then((Store store) => _store = store;);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _store?.close();  // don't forget to close the store
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

So I am lacking an idea on how an injector could initialize ObjectBox or how I could access the `objectBox` object from within the injected `JournalsRemoteDataSource` if I would initialize `objectBox` in `MyApp()` (which is upstream to the `HomePage`)

PS: reopening the box in `JournalsRemoteDataSource` on every read/write event has a very poor performance

========== UPDATE ==========
supplementing my comment to @vaind

I have found your answer on this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68466523/how-properly-use-the-objectbox-flutter-store-opening-and-closing) in the meantime (not sure why I did not see it, initially). I hope to get this approach working here, too. However, I have still issues initializing the store. My prototype comes from Firestore and looks like this:

```dart
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:injectable/injectable.dart';

@module
abstract class FirebaseInjectableModule {
  @lazySingleton
  FirebaseAuth get firebaseAuth => FirebaseAuth.instance;
}
```

though I do not understand where the getter `firebaseAuth` comes from and haven't found any explanation, yet. Anyways, I adapted that to

```dart
import 'package:injectable/injectable.dart';
import 'package:objectbox/objectbox.dart';
import 'package:test/objectbox.g.dart';

@module
abstract class ObjectboxInjectableModule {
  @lazySingleton
  Future<Store> get store async => await openStore();
}
```

and use this with

```dart
@LazySingleton (as: ILocalDataSource)
class ObjectBoxDataSource implements ILocalDataSource {
  final Store _store;
  final Box<JournalOboxEntity> _box;
  ObjectBoxDataSource(this._store) : _box = _store.box();
```

Besides `final Store _store` being grey in IntelliJ (unused variable), I receive the error

```dart
You tried to access an instance of Store that is not ready yet
'package:get_it/get_it_impl.dart':
Failed assertion: line 404 pos 9: 'instanceFactory.isReady'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So following another answer of vaind, I implemented this as follows. My architecture follows a merge of Reso Coder's DDD and Clean Architecture tutorials. Basically it is DDD with the local/remote data source layer of Clean Architecture.

INFRASTRUCTURE directory

abstract data sources

```dart
abstract class ILocalDataSource {
  Future<JournalDto> getJournal(int id);
  Future<void> storeJournal(JournalDto record);
}
abstract class IRemoteDataSource {
  Future<JournalDto> getJournal(int problemClassId);
}
```

data source implementation

```dart
@LazySingleton (as: ILocalDataSource)
class ObjectBoxDataSource implements ILocalDataSource {
  final Store _store;
  final Box<JournalOboxEntity> _box;
  ObjectBoxDataSource(this._store) : _box = _store.box();
```

injectable module in infrastructure/core

```dart
@module
abstract class ObjectBoxInjectableModule {
  @preResolve               // <<<<<<<<<<<<< needed for async init
  @lazySingleton
  Future<Store> get store async => await openStore();
}
```

And now the trick to get it work: My later errors where caused by an injector init not yet finished. After changing `injection.dart` in the root folder to a `Future` and `await`ing the call in `main()`, it worked. `injection.dart` now looks like this:

```dart
final GetIt getIt = GetIt.instance;

@injectableInit
Future<void> configureInjection(String env) async {
  $initGetIt(getIt, environment: env);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have experience with packages `get_it` & `injectable`, but from the docs, I think the following alternatives would work. Using `get_it` directly, not sure about the right way to achieve the same with `injectable` (generator for `get_it`) but I guess if you're familiar with it you can configure it to generate the same code.

#### Alternative A, lazy (async) singleton

```dart
GetIt.I.registerSingletonAsync<Store>(openStore);
```

#### Alternative B, setup in `main()`, probably preferrable

change your `main` to sth like:

```dart
void main() async {
  GetIt.I.registerSingleton<Store>(await openStore());
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Note: Looks like `get_it` provides a way to reset, which would result in reopening the same store. To avoid issues if you use that, you'd also need to implement a version of `get_it`'s `dispose` that calls `store.close()`.

Comment: Hey vaind, thanks for your answer. I am refactoring my code to the splendid tutorial of Reso Coder regarding DDD and unfortunately, I am also not familiar with those packages (why I moving from one problem to the next, currently). I am following a different approach based on another answer of yours and have updated my question accordingly. Maybe you have an idea, how to overcome the new hurdles...

Comment: got it, solution follows